Trying to find unique field isomorphisms, with field extensions
While navigating through some exercises I stumbled upon the following one. It had three field extensions K over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3,i)$, which I proved is a splitting field over  $\mathbb{Q}$
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ which I proved is not a splitting field over
$\mathbb{Q}$
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},i)$ also not a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ (for this I’m not sure but I took the polynomial $(x^2-3)(x^3-3) and \sqrt3$ does not belong in that extension

Now the exercise asks which of these have the property that there exists unique isomorphism of fields K->K. I’m thinking that for the second one, which is the only splitting field there could be multiple isomorphisms since a root can map to its conjugate through an isomorphism. So I’m clinging towards to the result that this one doesn’t have this property since we have at least two isomorphism, the identity and the one that maps an element to its complex conjugate. For the others, since they are not splitting fields and are just fields I don’t see why we could not have multiple isomorphisms. So, does none of the above extensions have the property? Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance

For the last field, how do you know that $\sqrt{3}$ does not belong there? Why exactly does it prove that it is not a splitting field?

@Adaya how can we construct $ \sqrt{3} $ from $ \sqrt[3]{3}$   and  $ i $ ? Sorry I can’t see it

@Adaya if the square root of 3 is not in there then it’s not a splitting field cause the polynomial I chose has that number as a solution
